# hybris CMSLinkComponent url attribute localization

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Generally we have url attribute for CMSLinkComponent, where we can save url value, in my scenario i want to make url as localized, we should add different url's for different languages. For this i tried to create CustomCMSLinkComponent by extending CMSLinkComponent, redeclared the url attribute to support localization.
I did ant all, then i can able to see url as localized but when am trying to save data in url am getting bellow errors
Its type: 'localized:java.lang.String' is not compatible to type: 'java.lang.String' of super attribute
Attribute: 'CustomCMSLinkComponent.url(localized:java.lang.String)::YAttributeDescriptor[xxxcore-items.xml:389(AttributeTagListener)][null]' is not properly redeclared
. Its type: 'localized:java.lang.String' is not compatible to type: 'java.lang.String' of super attribute: 'CMSLinkComponent.url(java.lang.String):((cms2))::YAttributeDescriptor

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: is there any solution for this ?